# ้How to Copy Some Content of Google Document Table to Google Spreadsheet By Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

**Are there any way to choose some content in the Google Document Table and copy to the Google Spreadsheet by the Google App Script**

Following with my photo idea
[image]

that I would like to copy some content in the red box / blue box to the Google Spreadsheet including with the data in  column name : level , Due Date 1, Due Date 2

I've started with the following code outline:

```
function Tables() {
var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();  
var tables = doc.getTables()[1]; 
for (var i = 0; i < tables.getNumRows(); ++i) {
  var cell = tables.getRow(i);
  var text =cell.getText();
  Logger.log(text);
} 
}
```

Comment: In order to correctly understand about your current situation, can you provide the sample Google Document?

Comment: @Tanaike Thank you for attention, Yes [These is my Sample Google Document (output)](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1-bS_Ib8shyJAvkNloTM-MhQ7a3iDLupiNcbC757Y4sI/edit?usp=sharing) and also I'm attached  [Sample Google Spreadsheet (input)](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10EISDEkShVvrwOEtPH6QM1emlY4W9p647suRzOEmWAw/edit?usp=sharing) Note. copy some content of Doc to Spreadsheet

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding the sample Document. Although I cannot see your sample Spreadsheet, when I saw your sample Document, it seems that your current sample document is different from your sample image in your question. So I'm confusing now. I apologize for this. In this case, even when I proposed a sample script, it might not be the result you expect. I deeply apologize for this.

Comment: @Tanaike, Thank you again, I'm apologize for changing the format while wait you for checking, I'm change it way back again I'm also attached the [Sample Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10EISDEkShVvrwOEtPH6QM1emlY4W9p647suRzOEmWAw/edit#gid=0) if you don't mind could you please suggest me,

Comment: Thank you for replying. Although, unfortunately, I cannot open your sample Spreadsheet, from your sample Google Document and sample output image, I proposed a sample script for your sample Google Document. Could you please confirm it? This sample script can be used for your sample Google Document. If the structure of your Document is changed, the script might be required to be modified. So please be careful this. **When you test this script, please use your sample Google Document.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I cannot see your sample Spreadsheet, from your sample Google Document and sample output image, I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to retrieve the values from the 1st table in Google Document and put the values to Google Spreadsheet by converting the values as follows.

  - From

    [image]
  - To

    [image]

#### Modification points:

- In your script, 2nd table is retrieved. In your sample Document, an error occurs.
- In your case, I think that it is required to retrieve the values from each cell. But in your script, the values are directly retrieved from the rows.
- In your script, the values are only retrieved from the rows. In order to achieve your goal, it is required to convert the retrieved values from Document for putting to Spreadsheet.

When above points are reflected to a script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor and set the variables and run the script. About the variable of `excludeTexts`, in this case, these values are from your sample Google Document. When you change the exclude text line in the table of Document, please modify the values.

```
function myFunction() {
  const documentId = "###";  // Please set Document ID.
  const spreadsheetId = "###";  // Please set Spreadsheet ID of the destination Spreadsheet.
  const sheetName = "Sheet1";  // Please set the sheet name of the destination sheet.
  const excludeTexts = ["Part A:", "Part B:", "Part C:"];  // Please set the exclude texts.

  // 1. Retrieve values from 1st table from Document and create an array for putting to Spreadsheet.
  // const body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody(); // If you copy and paste the script to the container-bound script of Document, you can use this line instead of "DocumentApp.openById(documentId).getBody()".
  const body = DocumentApp.openById(documentId).getBody();
  const table = body.getTables()[0];
  let values = [];
  for (let r = 0; r < table.getNumRows(); r++) {
    const cell = table.getRow(r);
    const row = [];
    for (let c = 0; c < cell.getNumCells(); c++) {
      const text = cell.getCell(c).getText().trim();
      row.push(r > 0 && c == 1 ? text.split("\n").map(e => e.trim()).filter(e => !excludeTexts.includes(e)) : text);
    }
    values = values.concat(Array.isArray(row[1]) ? row[1].map((e, i) => i == 0 ? [row[0], e, ...row.slice(2)] : ["",e,...Array(row.slice(2).length).fill("")]) : [row]);
  }
  console.log(values)

  // 2. Put the created array to Spreadsheet.
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId).getSheetByName(sheetName);
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```

- When above script is run for your Google Document, the sample situation at the top images is obtained.

#### Note:

- **This sample script can be used for your sample Google Document. If the structure of your Document is changed, the script might be required to be modified. So please be careful this. When you test this script, please use your sample Google Document.**

#### References:

- [getRow(rowIndex)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/table#getrowrowindex)
- [getCell(cellIndex)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/table-row#getCell(Integer))

Comment: Thank you for your assistance, I'm try to test your Modified script then I'm got the result following my goal Thanks again

Comment: If you don't mind, Could you please explain me for the script that why when the script run and found some content containing The Numbering [1.] / Bullet [.][example as 1. Do you like apple?] it don't retrieve The Numbering / Bullet to the Google Sheet and other one when it found the The Numbering / Bullet why it retrieve  the content to Google Sheet with seperate row not the sam as Group of contents which retrieve  the content to Google Sheet with the same row Thank you again

Comment: @Vash Kris I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from your replying, I cannot understand about your new question. Can I ask you about the detail of your new question? By this, I would like to try to understand it. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill again.

Comment: @Tanaki Sorry for my unclear question I'm attached the image including the question Could you please see it [Question](https://drive.google.com/file/d/17KJGs3aVTmlarIwrNWqSFel6_Zylb7pu/view?usp=sharing) if you can't see it please inform me Thank you again

Comment: @Vash Kris Thank you for replying. I could see your sample file. When I saw it, I thought that it's new issue. I would like to support you. But the issue of your comment is new issue, and that is different from your question. So can you post it as new question by including the detail information? Because when your initial question is changed by comment, other users who see your question are confused. By posting it as new question, users including me can think of it. If you can cooperate to resolve your new issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to resolve your new question?

Comment: Thank you I'm will follow your suggestion

Comment: @Vash Kris Thank you for your response. When I found your new question, I would like to check it.